# Flutter: minor errors when launching app to Android emulator

Tags: flutter

When I launch an app to an Android emulator, I get the following two error messages, but the app works fine:

```
E/SurfaceSyncer( 6710): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 6710): Expecting binder but got null!
```

Environment: Windows 11, AMD Ryzen 6000
Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.674], locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

No errors occur if I instead launch to Chrome.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Visual Studio? This contains the 'Desktop development with C++' which flutter seems to require. (Visual Studio != Visual Studio *Code*)

Comment: No, because I'm not doing Windows development.